# Creating a simple XFinium PDF on iOS containing an image

Tags: c#, pdf, xamarin.forms

We're using XFinium on our C# Xamarin Forms app on iOS.  I had some test code that would create a PDF with a couple of pieces of text and it worked correctly.  However, when I tried to include an image, the resulting PDF doesn't contain the image and Acrobat Reader gives the "An error exists on this page".  The image in question is a resource in my application (not loaded from URL).

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
string file = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "report.pdf");
PdfFixedDocument document = new PdfFixedDocument();
PdfStandardFont helveticaBold = new PdfStandardFont(PdfStandardFontFace.HelveticaBold, 16);
PdfPage page = document.Pages.Add();
page.Width = 8 * 72 + 36;
page.Height = 11 * 72;
PdfBrush blackBrush = new PdfBrush(PdfRgbColor.Black);
page.Graphics.DrawString("Hello", helveticaBold, blackBrush, 20, 50);
string imageFileName = "UI_Assets_Image.png";
FileStream imageStream = System.IO.File.Open(imageFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
PdfPngImage image = new PdfPngImage(imageStream);
Debug.WriteLine("   image is " + image.Width + " x " + image.Height);
// Reports 1373 x 417 which is correct so I believe it is
// loading the image correctly
// Draw image in the page width
PdfSize size = page.Graphics.DrawImage(image, 36, 75, 540, 166);
Debug.WriteLine("   DrawImage() returned " + size.Width + " x " + size.Height);
// Reports 540 x 166 which seems reasonable
using (FileStream stream = System.IO.File.Create(file))
{
    document.Save(stream, null);
}
```

If I don't include the image, the PDF is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears because the PNG image is not a proper PNG image, it has been optimized during build process for usage with iOS methods and classes.
If you disable the PNG optimization in the project settings the image should be displayed correctly in the PDF file.

Comment: Interesting!  I didn't realize that option existed.  However, it's already unchecked ("Optimize PNG images" is off).

Comment: But when I print the value of imageStream.Length, it doesn't match the size of my original PNG file.  So maybe the build is optimizing the PNG whether I tell it to or not.

Comment: Try changing the file extension to something else, xpng for example. The PNG optimization option must be disabled for all build configurations.

Comment: When I brought up the Properties for my iOS project, "Optimize PNG Images" was unchecked.  But when I checked it and then unchecked it, my csproj file changed to include the line "<OptimizePNGs>false</OptimizePNGs>" and if I then delete my bin and obj files and rebuild, it works!